# Overwriting css variables in selector scope does not update gradient angle

Tags: css, css-variables, css-gradients

```css
:root {
    --color-primary: #1999CC;
    --gr-deg-x: 270deg;
    --gr-primary-fade-x: linear-gradient(var(--gr-deg-x), var(--color-primary) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
}

.myselector {
    --gr-deg-x: 180deg;
    background: var(--gr-primary-fade-x);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="myselector"></div>
```

The background gradient angle for `.myselector` is still `270deg` instead of `180deg`. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to update a variable in another variable. But you can do the following: `background:  linear-gradient(var(--gr-deg-x), var(--color-primary) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);`. So you will need to write the gradient again and not using a variable. Or you can make a variable for each direction. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @WebPrograme Do you know of any spec description of this? Some off. documentation?